# Celery gives no error with bad remote task names, why?

Tags: python, django, celery

Using "send_task" celery actually never verifies a remote task exists i.e:

```
app.send_task('tasks.i.dont.exist', args=[], kwargs={})
```

Celery seems to still return a message i.e.:

```
<AsyncResult: b8c1425a-7411-491f-b75a-34313832b8ba>
```

Is there a way for it to fail if the remote task does not exist?

I've tried adding `.get()` and it just freezes.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:

> If the task is not registered in the current process then you can also
>   execute a task by name.
>
> You do this by using the send_task() method of the celery instance

If you want verification consider using `delay` instead.

You can read more about how to execute celery tasks [here](https://ask.github.io/celery/userguide/executing.html).